# BigQuery Classic UI fails to show estimated cost and always shows "This query will process 0 B when run."

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed this issue - can be quite bad for users if they don't check size of querying table(s) by their own.

No matter how really heavy query in terms of bytes to be processed - I see below

[image]

Looks like this feature is broken on Classic UI since recently. What can I do?

Note: not really programmatic question but I thought critical enough to expose this hopefully temporary issue to users

Comment: Tracking https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143577567

Comment: looks like still an issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option you have is to either use BigQuery New UI (I double checked and this is not broken there) or to use third party tools like Potens.io as an example

> Update :

This was fixed and now estimated bytes and respective cost is available in Classic UI

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try bigquery-mate chrome browser plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh?hl=en-US

Or
even a better solution for your org: 
https://potens.io/products/#goliath

Comment: just to clarify - issue is on Google side and is still open [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143577567). Meantime, i went ahead and added Cost Estimation for BQ Mate for New UI (console). And, yes - agree - the best option I know so far is Goliath - part of Potens Suite